# Adding Sheet object to Collection causes RTE 438-Object doesnt support this method

Tags: vba, excel, collections

I'm trying to add a Sheet object to a blank Collection.

> Line: SheetsCollection.Add (wbTested.Sheets(1))

I want to use this collection of sheets to print their details later in another function.

The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub TestPrintWorksheetsNames()

    Dim wbTested As Workbook
    Dim SheetsCollection As New Collection

    Set wbTested = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/AddinFunctionsKollarBTestWB.xlsx")
    SheetsCollection.Add (wbTested.Sheets(1))

    With wbTested
        Debug.Print .Name
        Call PrintWorksheetsNames(SheetsCollection)
    End With 'wbTested

    wbTested.Close savechanges:=False
    Set wbTested = Nothing
End Sub
```

The highlighted line throws an runtime error *438 Object doesnt support this property or method*.
**Can you please help me with this? Is it possible to add Object types to Collection Object? How?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove brackets

```
SheetsCollection.Add wbTested.Sheets(1)
```